# HasTraits overiding inherited getter/setter methods

Tags: python, enthought, traits

I would like to mix a `HasTraits`  with a standard python `object` using multiple inheritance. When  i do this, the getter/setter methods of the standard object dont function as expected. The example below demonstrates this.

```
from traits.api import HasTraits


class A(object):
    @property
    def name(self):
        print 'getter'
        try:
            return self._name
        except(AttributeError):
            return 'nobody'

    @name.setter
    def name(self, val):
        print 'setter'
        self._name = val.upper()

class B(A, HasTraits):
    pass


b = B()
b.name  #calls getter 

b.name = 'name' # doesnt call setter
b.name # doesnt call getter
```

I assume this is because the `HasTraits` class intercepts the standard get/set methods. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I am a complete ignorant on the traits lib (thank you for introducing me to it, quite useful stuff), but have you tried inverting the inheritance chain to `class B(HasTraits, A)`? It may be a silly thing to do, let me know

Comment: does not change behavior, no.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is not a way to make traits play nicely with the native python decorator `@property`. At least, not any reasonably clean way.

However traits has its own `Property` concept with getters and setters. You can define a `Property` trait which does what you want as a simple getter/setter.

```
class B(A, HasTraits):
    this_name = Property
    def _get_this_name(self):
      return self.name
    def _set_this_name(self, value):
      self.name = value
```

And if you subclass a `HasTraits` which contains a `Property`, that traits-specific getter/setter effects will be preserved in the subclass. So there is no reason -- that is if you already want the type-checking of traits in your program -- to use the `@property` decorator and not the `Property` getter in the first place.